# ASP MVC routing 404 and images issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a problem with my routing. I am trying to prevent 404 errors to end up in my custom routeconstraint.

This is some of my routes:

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allfiles}", new { allfiles = @".*\.(css|js|gif|jpg|png)" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "MenuRoute",
            url: "{*permalink}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Menu", action = "Index" },
            constraints: new { permalink = new MenuUrlConstraint() }
        );
```

My issue is that everytime a 404 appears for static files they go to my MenuRoute.

Is there a way for me to avoid this happening?

Or is the only solution to check for 404 in my routeconstraint, and do nothing if so?

-----EDIT----

```
public class MenuUrlConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {

        var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var permalink = values[parameterName] != null ? values[parameterName].ToString() : "";
        return db.MenuItems.Any(p => p.Url == permalink && p.Published == true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Routing works like a switch case statement in `c#`. If a route constraint returns true, it causes routing to use the current route and not check any routes configured after it.

So, yes a possible solution would be to use a guard clause to ensure a 404 status cannot ever return true.

```
if (httpContext.Response.StatusCode == 404) return false;
```

There might be a better solution to ensuring your route constraint only returns true when you want it to, but since you didn't post the code, I can't offer up a suggestion.

Comment: Hi, The constraint will return false when its a 404 already. However, the routeconstraint checks the DB for slugs etc. I dont need that if 404 on images etc obviously:> As you said, I could do what your suggestion in my constraint. I was thinking that perhaps this could be avoided if the general routes where setup different or something?  Ill post my routeconstraint in EDIT on original question.